# Can a Balanced customer use an Etrade account?

Tags: balanced-payments

Can a Balanced user use an Etrade account as their funding source / payout destination?

These accounts have standard routing and account numbers but it is not clear if credits and debits are accepted in the normal way.

If this is possible, does the customer need to set up authorization etc. with Etrade before using Balanced?

Thanks!

https://us.etrade.com/home

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trading.

Comment: please ask question as per the forum is for

Comment: This question is not about trading, Evan - it is about compatibility of Balanced with a specific funding and receiving account type.
Saurabh, please rephrase your point as it is not clear what you are saying.

Comment: If clarification is necessary: can Balanced (www.balancedpayments.com) credit funds to, and debit funds from, an eTrade account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Etrade account has a routing number and account number like any other bank account in the US then it will be compatible.

If it's a *virtual* bank account that can only be accessed via the Etrade website then it will not work.

Balanced uses the ACH network to perform credit and debit operations on bank accounts so there is nothing specific to a particular bank.